# How to add same number to same string in python?

Tags: python, string, text

I want to give same number to the same string name and save it to text file.

For example if there are multiple strings name "Ball" from filename, then I will give this string number 0. Another example, if I have multiple strings name "Square" from filename, then I will give this string number 1. And so on.

I tried using os.path.walk and splitting the text but still have no idea how to add the number and save it to text file

```py
with open("check.txt", "w") as a:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for i, filename in enumerate(files):

            #the filename have underscore to separate the space
            #for example Ball_red_move

            mylist = filename.split("_") 

            #I tried to take the first string name only after splitting, here 
            #for example "Ball"

            k = mylist[0]

            #After this I don't have idea to add number when the string name 
            #is same and also save it to txt file with the directory name
```

This is my expected result:

```
Check/Ball_red_move_01 0

Check/Ball_red_move_02 0

Check/Ball_red_move_03 0


Check/Square_jump_forward_01 1

Check/Square_jump_forward_02 1

Check/Square_jump_forward_03 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You might like to do something like this:

Prepare a dictionary to map the string to some labeling numbers and check if the string is present.

```
object_map = {'Ball': 0, 'Square': 1}

def get_num_from_string(x):
    for i in object_map:
        if i in x:
            return object_map[i]

A = ['Check/Ball_red_move_01', 'Check/Square_jump_forward_01']

for i in A:
    print(i + ' '+str(get_num_from_string(i)))
```

This produces

```
Check/Ball_red_move_01 0
Check/Square_jump_forward_01 1
```

A few thing for you to consider, what do you want to do none of the string appears and also what do you want to do if multiple strings appear.